# Filebeat 7.5.1 Missing a step for custom index names config?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I should be able to see a new custom index name **dev-7.5.1-yyyy.MM.dd** within Kibana, but instead it is still called filebeat.

I have the following set it my ***filebeat.yml*** config file, which should allow me to see dev-* index in Kibana. However these are still indexing as filebeat-7.5.1-yyyy-MM.dd. Filebeat is running on a ec2 instance that can communicate with the elastic-search server on port 9200.

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /var/log/*.log

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["my_es_host_ip:9200"]
  index: "dev-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

setup.template.enabled: true
setup.template.name: "dev-%{[agent.version]}"
setup.template.pattern: "dev-%{[agent.version]}-*"
```

Is there step I'm missing? From reading over the the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-template.html) and the [reference file](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/filebeat/filebeat.reference.yml), I believe I have everything set correctly.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the following setting is needed in his case:

`setup.ilm.enabled: false`

After adding that to my config, it worked as expected. There is a open issue to improve how to find this out here: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/11866

Comment: filebeat-7.9.3 I tried your solution but it did not work though..

Answer (score 1):

Use these configuration to have customer index template and name.

```
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.template.name: "dev"
setup.template.pattern: "dev-*"
index: "dev-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

> When index lifecycle management (ILM) is enabled, the default index is
> "filebeat-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}-%{index_num}", for
> example, "filebeat-7.13.0-2021-05-25-000001". Custom index settings
> are ignored when ILM is enabled. If you’re sending events to a cluster
> that supports index lifecycle management, see Index lifecycle
> management (ILM) to learn how to change the index name.
>
> If index lifecycle management is enabled (which is typically the
> default), setup.template.name and setup.template.pattern are ignored.

Ref:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/change-index-name.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-template.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/ilm.html